# Need to redirect to previous page after submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to redirect to `premontessori` page after submitting the form. How can  i do this?

this is my `handleSubmit` function:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     <Link to='/premontessori' style={{textDecoration:'none'}} > alert("New Student Created");</Link>
     var data= {
           Fname:this.state.Fname,
           age:this.state.age,
           Lname:this.state.Lname,
           dob:this.state.dob,
           pob:this.state.pob,
           month:this.state.month,
           nation:this.state.nation,
           mothertongue:this.state.mothertongue,
           bloodgroup:this.state.bloodgroup
      };
      axios.post('/create',data)
        .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Import` the kind of `history object` you are using like `hashHistory` or `browserHistory`.

`import {hashHistory} from 'react-router';`

and use

`hashHistory.push('/premontessori');`

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is after submitting it's redirecting to premontessori but what ever i submitted is not displaying in the premontessori page. What should i do now?

Comment: You can store the data in some store like redux or flux than reload the data from there, another option is pass all the values summited in url query params like hashHistory.push('/premontessori?a=b&c=d') and fetch values in premontessori component using this.props.location.query.a

Answer (score 1):

You can use react router(e.g.-hashHistory) for navigating.

```
hashHistory.goBack();
```

Answer (score 1):

Link is not the correct way for dynamic routing. You need to make use of context.router to navigate to the previous route

If your component name is `MyComponent` then add the below line outside the component

```
MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

And navigate like `this.props.context.router.push('routename');`

I will recommend you to do this inside the `axios success` callback and not before it

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ..............
    handleSubmit(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var self = this;
            var data= {Fname:this.state.Fname,
               age:this.state.age,
               Lname:this.state.Lname,
               dob:this.state.dob,
               pob:this.state.pob,
               month:this.state.month,
               nation:this.state.nation,
               mothertongue:this.state.mothertongue,
               bloodgroup:this.state.bloodgroup
              };
            axios.post('/create',data)
            .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
             self.context.router.push('/premontessori')
           })
         }
     ..............
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Outside the component?

Comment: i have put those lines outside the component as you said but it's giving me an error as Cannot set property 'contextTypes' of undefined

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is after submitting it's redirecting to premontessori but what ever i submitted is not displaying in the premontessori page. What should i do now?

Comment: You mean to say you want to show data object attributes in premontessori page

Comment: actually in premontessori page i am displaying a list of students from the database. So whenever i submit a new data will be stored in the database and  then i am fetching those data and displaying it in premontesori page

Comment: It shosuld be easy then. you should be fetching the data of list of students in the componentDidMount function of premontessori component and that should work

Comment: Yeah i am fetching data there only. But as soon as it redirects i see old lists but the new added data won't appear until i hit refresh

Comment: I am just guessing, Your database may take time to update with the latest result. So I think what you can do is have a load your data in a setTimeout function in componentDidMount, give a duration of say 5 sec and see if it works

Comment: It might work. But if i do so every time it will take 5sec to reload right??

Comment: You can try to.see if it's working, if yes then see you whole page will not rerender only the   updated entry will be rendered . that's the beauty of react

Comment: Yeah ok will try and tell you.

Comment: It's working but as i said it will take 5sec to display data if i just refresh the page

Comment: you can decrease the timeout time, maybe 2 sec or so, this is what I can think of.

Comment: I have found out the answer. Instead of giving timer to premontessori page i have given timer to history.goback() like this   setTimeout(  () =>  {hashHistory.goBack();  },1000);   and it's working fine!!

Comment: This will be one and the same thing, anyway whatever you prefer,.

Comment: No. Because if i refresh premontessori page it won't reload after 1sec. Instead after submitting going back to the premontessori page is delayed thats it. Any ways thanks for your response.